# Two Bootstrap popover titles inside a single popover

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a slight issue

I have this line of code

```
<i style="font-size:28px;" class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="popover" id='example' title="text is entered here, Text two also is here. data-content="two forms of content will be here"></i>
```

Ideally i'm wanting to have two headers so i can have an info tag that has 2 parts of detail inside rather than one big popover tab.

Ideally it would end up looking like this

```
/////////////////////////////
//////////Title//////////////
/////////////////////////////
//                         //
//                         //
//        Content          //
//                         //
//                         //
/////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////
///////////Title/////////////
/////////////////////////////
//                         //
//                         //
//        Content          //
//                         //
//                         //
/////////////////////////////
```

Thanks a lot! And i hope you enjoy the time and effort placed into the picture above!

**Edit**

Missed JS Code, See Below

```
$('#example').popover({placement: 'right'});
```

Comment: please include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or at least show [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) rather than asking for others to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with custom popover options in boostrap :

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options

and check content option :

```
$('#example').popover({
    placement: 'right',
    html: true,
    content: function() {
        return '<h3 class="title1">Title 1</h3><div class="content1">Content 1</div><h3 class="title2">Title 2</h3><div class="content2">Content 2</div>';
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var events = [
 {
    title: 'title here',
    description: 'body here',
    backgroundColor: '#CC0000'
  }, {
    title: 'title2',
    description: 'heyyy',
    backgroundColor: '#00CC00'
  }
];
var popup = '';
$.each(events, function(key, event) {
    popup += '<h3 class="popover-header whiteTxt font-weight-bold" style="background-color: ' + event.backgroundColor + ';"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i> &nbsp; ' + event.title + '</h3>' + ((event.description) ? '<p class="mb-0">' + event.description + '</p>' : '');
});

$('#button-popover').popover({
 boundary:   'window',
  content:    popup,
  html:       true,
  template:   '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-body p-0"></div></div>',
  trigger:    'hover'
});
```

```css
.whiteTxt {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<button id="button-popover">Popover with multiple items</button>
```

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question?